# Unity - UI Mobile - Script Generated buttons/text not seen?

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate some buttons and text dynamically with Unity 5.0
All of my code seems proper.  It looks great when I play it in the editor. Everything is generated and placed and sized as I want for a first run.  I Made the apk.  Installed it onto my phone with no problems.
Upon opening the thing I see my static Canvas objects but my dynamics are nowhere.  I made them gigantic just to be sure.

Details:
Unity 5.0.  I have my build settings set for Android 5 which I have on my phone. I tried Android 4.6.

My Canvas UI Scale mode is now set to Scale with Screen Size.
My preview is set to WXGA Portrait 800 x 1280 which is the resolution of my One Note 4 according to the spec sheet on the Samsung web site. 
Canvas Reference Resolution is X 800 Y 1280.
All static and dynamic objects are children of the Canvas

What am I missing?  I feel like it's some option somewhere I overlooked.

Comment: An issue with font embedding? Are you using the default font?

Comment: I will find out this afternoon.  I recall having an issue like this before.  Android doesn't support dynamic fonts or something but I am unable to find reliable information on dealing with this issue or even getting a proper definition of it.  Does Unity not override the font and handle it manually? Would NGUI?

Comment: I am using the default font which is Arial.

Answer (score 0):

I had done this (generating dynamic buttons) using the following code

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate<GameObject>(btn_prefab);
obj.transform.SetParent(parent);

float itemXPosition = normalizedItemCenter + (normalizedItemWidth * index);

obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(itemXPosition, 0.0f);
obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(itemXPosition, 1.0f);
obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.Set(size.x, size.y);
```

Here

- `btn_prefab` is a prefab of a button that I am creating.
- `parent` is the parent RectTransform Object inside which I want my buttons.
- `normalizedItemCenter` and `normalizedItemWidth` are centre and width of the button in scale of 0.0 to 1.0
- `index` is the number of button being generated (I am generating multiple buttons inside a loop)
- `size.x` and `size.y` are calculated width and height (respectively) for the buttons

Note: All this is done after assign a parent to the button. This is a common mistake that developers first play with the transform of the GameObject and then assign them a parent (which should be done in certain cases and is also useful) but in a case like this one they are extremely teasing and frustrating as you are not getting your desired result and it also becomes difficult to find the problem.